# componentDidMount function not working when importing and using in different project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

My library is located at https://github.com/nitinkushwaha/react-sticky-scroll-spy

So when I import this library to my project then componentDidMount function is not executing and every other function goes well.

Library file location https://github.com/nitinkushwaha/react-sticky-scroll-spy/blob/master/src/react-sticky-scroll-spy.js

Code is:

```
import React from 'react';

class ReactStickyScrollSpy extends React.Component{
    constructor (props) {
        console.log('was in constructor');
        super(props);
        this.easingEffects = {
            linear: function(t) {
                return t
            },
            easeInQuad: function(t) {
                return t * t
            },
            easeOutQuad: function(t) {
                return -1 * t * (t - 2)
            },
            easeInOutQuad: function(t) {
                return (t /= .5) < 1 ? .5 * t * t : -.5 * (--t * (t - 2) - 1)
            },
            easeInCubic: function(t) {
                return t * t * t
            },
            easeOutCubic: function(t) {
                return 1 * ((t = t / 1 - 1) * t * t + 1)
            },
            easeInOutCubic: function(t) {
                return (t /= .5) < 1 ? .5 * t * t * t : .5 * ((t -= 2) * t * t + 2)
            },
            easeInQuart: function(t) {
                return t * t * t * t
            },
            easeOutQuart: function(t) {
                return -1 * ((t = t / 1 - 1) * t * t * t - 1)
            },
            easeInOutQuart: function(t) {
                return (t /= .5) < 1 ? .5 * t * t * t * t : -.5 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t - 2)
            },
            easeInQuint: function(t) {
                return 1 * (t /= 1) * t * t * t * t
            },
            easeOutQuint: function(t) {
                return 1 * ((t = t / 1 - 1) * t * t * t * t + 1)
            },
            easeInOutQuint: function(t) {
                return (t /= .5) < 1 ? .5 * t * t * t * t * t : .5 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t * t + 2)
            },
            easeInSine: function(t) {
                return -1 * Math.cos(t / 1 * (Math.PI / 2)) + 1
            },
            easeOutSine: function(t) {
                return 1 * Math.sin(t / 1 * (Math.PI / 2))
            },
            easeInOutSine: function(t) {
                return -.5 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * t / 1) - 1)
            },
            easeInExpo: function(t) {
                return 0 === t ? 1 : 1 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t / 1 - 1))
            },
            easeOutExpo: function(t) {
                return 1 === t ? 1 : 1 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / 1) + 1)
            },
            easeInOutExpo: function(t) {
                return 0 === t ? 0 : 1 === t ? 1 : (t /= .5) < 1 ? .5 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) : .5 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2)
            },
            easeInCirc: function(t) {
                return 1 > t ? -1 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t /= 1) * t) - 1) : t
            },
            easeOutCirc: function(t) {
                return 1 * Math.sqrt(1 - (t = t / 1 - 1) * t)
            },
            easeInOutCirc: function(t) {
                return (t /= .5) < 1 ? -.5 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) - 1) : .5 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t -= 2) * t) + 1)
            },
            easeInElastic: function(t) {
                var e = 1.70158,
                    n = 0,
                    i = 1;
                return 0 === t ? 0 : 1 == (t /= 1) ? 1 : (n || (n = .3), i < Math.abs(1) ? (i = 1, e = n / 4) : e = n / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(1 / i), -(i * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin(2 * (1 * t - e) * Math.PI / n)))
            },
            easeOutElastic: function(t) {
                var e = 1.70158,
                    n = 0,
                    i = 1;
                return 0 === t ? 0 : 1 == (t /= 1) ? 1 : (n || (n = .3), i < Math.abs(1) ? (i = 1, e = n / 4) : e = n / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(1 / i), i * Math.pow(2, -10 * t) * Math.sin(2 * (1 * t - e) * Math.PI / n) + 1)
            },
            easeInOutElastic: function(t) {
                var e = 1.70158,
                    n = 0,
                    i = 1;
                return 0 === t ? 0 : 2 == (t /= .5) ? 1 : (n || (n = .3 * 1.5), i < Math.abs(1) ? (i = 1, e = n / 4) : e = n / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(1 / i), 1 > t ? -.5 * i * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin(2 * (1 * t - e) * Math.PI / n) : i * Math.pow(2, -10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin(2 * (1 * t - e) * Math.PI / n) * .5 + 1)
            },
            easeInBack: function(t) {
                var e = 1.70158;
                return 1 * (t /= 1) * t * ((e + 1) * t - e)
            },
            easeOutBack: function(t) {
                var e = 1.70158;
                return 1 * ((t = t / 1 - 1) * t * ((e + 1) * t + e) + 1)
            },
            easeInOutBack: function(t) {
                var e = 1.70158;
                return (t /= .5) < 1 ? .5 * t * t * (((e *= 1.525) + 1) * t - e) : .5 * ((t -= 2) * t * (((e *= 1.525) + 1) * t + e) + 2)
            },
            easeInBounce: function(t) {
                return 1 - easingEffects.easeOutBounce(1 - t)
            },
            easeOutBounce: function(t) {
                return (t /= 1) < 1 / 2.75 ? 7.5625 * t * t : 2 / 2.75 > t ? 1 * (7.5625 * (t -= 1.5 / 2.75) * t + .75) : 2.5 / 2.75 > t ? 1 * (7.5625 * (t -= 2.25 / 2.75) * t + .9375) : 1 * (7.5625 * (t -= 2.625 / 2.75) * t + .984375)
            },
            easeInOutBounce: function(t) {
                return .5 > t ? .5 * easingEffects.easeInBounce(2 * t) : .5 * easingEffects.easeOutBounce(2 * t - 1) + .5
            }
        };
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        console.log('was here');
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent.bind(this, this));

        this.menuItems = this.refs.sticky.getElementsByTagName('a');
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        this.scrollItems = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.menuItems.length; i++) {
            let item = this.menuItems.item(i);
            if (item.getAttribute('href').length) {
                this.scrollItems.push(item);
                item.addEventListener('click', this.linkClick.bind(this, this));
            }
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount () {
        console.log('was in unmount');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent);
        for(var i = 0; i < this.scrollItems.length; i++) {
            let item = this.scrollItems.item(i);
            item.removeEventListener('click', this.linkClick);
        }
    }
    render() {
        console.log('was in render');
        return (
            <div ref="sticky">
                <div>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    scrollEvent (_self, event) {
        //this.scrollItems
        let cur = [];
        let currentScroll = event.srcElement.body.scrollTop;
        for (let i = 0; i < _self.scrollItems.length; i++) {
            let href = _self.scrollItems[i].getAttribute('href');
            if (href != '#') {
                let elementOffsetTop = document.getElementById(href.slice(1)).offsetTop;
                if (elementOffsetTop < currentScroll + _self.refs.sticky.childNodes[0].offsetHeight)
                    cur.push(href);
            } else {
                cur.push('#');
            }
        }
        cur = cur[cur.length-1];
        for (let i = 0; i < _self.menuItems.length; i++) {
            if (cur == _self.menuItems[i].getAttribute('href')) {
                _self.menuItems[i].parentNode.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                _self.menuItems[i].parentNode.classList.remove('active');
            }
        }

        let elementHeightTop = _self.refs.sticky.offsetTop;
        if (elementHeightTop <= currentScroll) {
            if (!_self.isFixed) {
                let elementHeight = _self.refs.sticky.childNodes[0].offsetHeight;
                _self.refs.sticky.style.height = elementHeight + 'px';

                let childElement =  _self.refs.sticky.childNodes[0].style;
                childElement.position = 'fixed';
                childElement.top = '0px';
                _self.isFixed = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (_self.isFixed) {
                _self.refs.sticky.style.height = 'auto';
                let childElement =  _self.refs.sticky.childNodes[0].style;
                childElement.position = 'relative';
                childElement.top = 'auto';
                _self.isFixed = false;
            }
        }
    }
    linkClick (_self, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let element = event.target;
        let href = element.getAttribute('href');
        let offsetTop = (href === "#") ? 0 : document.getElementById(href.slice(1)).offsetTop - _self.refs.sticky.childNodes[0].offsetHeight+1;
        _self.scrollToY(offsetTop);
    }
    scrollToY (scrollHeight) {
        let _self = this;
        let scrollStep = 600/15;
        let currentScrollStep = 1;

        requestAnimationFrame(step);
        function step () {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if ( scrollStep >= currentScrollStep ) {
                    requestAnimationFrame(step);
                    let currentStep = (100/scrollStep)*currentScrollStep;
                    currentScrollStep++;
                    let scrollRatio = _self.easingEffects.easeInQuart(currentStep/100);
                    let yPosScroll = (window.scrollY - scrollHeight) * scrollRatio;
                    window.scrollTo( 0, ( window.scrollY - yPosScroll ));
                }
            }, 15 );
        }
    }
}

export default ReactStickyScrollSpy
```

Dev mode can be started with npm start and url is localhost:3000

Library is build using npm run build

Any suggestion will be appreciated :)

Comment: How do you import and use your library in your application code?

Answer (score 0):

The component will be mounted as soon as `{this.props.children}` is/are mounted. did you tried to remove `{this.props.children}` and see if `componentDidMount()` triggers?

It could be an issue with one of the children not rendering or breaking JavaScripts. Is there any error logs in the console?

Comment: nope, there are no errors and I have trie after removing children still no success :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you do server side rendering? when rendering server side, `componentDidMount` is not trigerred client side. That can be verified reading your command line promp. Any trace of 'was here'?

Comment: Its client side rendering

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone I got the answer, actually react in my library was of latest version whereas the project had older version.